# How to get time spent inside loop

Tags: jmeter

I have written a load test for a web application. The test script submits a request to the server via HTTP and then polls the server in a While loop with a small timer, to see when the request has been processed. The problem I am having is that in all the listeners (aggregate graph, table, etc.) JMeter only shows the time each request took and not the total time to process the job, i.e. time from initial request sent until response that contains the expected "complete" message.

How can I add something like "profiling points" which will get data onto the listeners graphs? Or is there another way this is typically handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller). Put elements times of which you want to aggregate under it. Transaction controller will then appear in all your listeners. Its load and latency times will be sums of those parameters of its nested elements.

> Note that this time by default includes all processing within the controller scope, not just the samples, this can be changed by unchecking "Include duration of timer and pre-post processors in generated sample".